# Finding the height of a building given two angles of elevation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Um observador vê um prédio, no nível do solo, construído em terreno
plano, sob um ângulo de 60º. Afastando-se do edifício mais 30m,
passa a ver o edifício sob ângulo de 45º. Qual é a altura do prédio?

Translation?:  An observer views a building, constructed on flat terrain, from ground level, at an angle of $60^\circ$. Moving away another $30$ meters, he now sees it from an angle of $45^\circ$. What is the height of the building?

answer: $\frac{30\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-1}$

[image: Height of building]

Comment: You can build on terrain plane at an angle of 60 degrees?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I tried to attach a photo, but the site did not allow ...

Comment: I'm Brazilian, I think I've traded it wrong for your language ... it's there now in my language.

Comment: I believe that should be translated as moving "30 feet more" (i.e. 30 additional feet) from the building, not "more than 30 feet" from the building.

Comment: Only here in Brazil meters are equivalent to feet!
30 meters = 98.4252 feet

Comment: And yes, your analysis is right, it is moving away more from the edifice in 30 meters

Comment: My Portuguese is rusty, but I would translate this as, "An observer views a building, constructed on flat terrain, from ground level, at an angle of $60^\circ.$  Moving away another $30$ meters, he now sees it from an angle of $45^\circ.$  What is the height of the building?"

Comment: You have two equations for $h$. One expresses the tangent of $60^\circ$ in terms of $h$ and a variable $x$ and the other expresses the tangent of $45^\circ$ in terms of $h$ and $x+30$. You should be able to solve those two equations in $x$ and $h$ for both $x$ and $h$.

Comment: thank you brothers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I do not know Portuguese, so this answer is in English.

Let the initial distance between the observer and the building be $x$m.

Then, from the figure,
$$\begin{align}
\tan 60^0 &= \dfrac{h}{x} \\
\tan 45^0 &= \dfrac{h}{x+30} 
\end{align}$$

So, we get,
$$h = \sqrt{3}x$$
$$h = x + 30$$

Now, eliminate $x$ and you will get,

$$h = \dfrac{30\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-1}$$

Comment: thank you friend!

Comment: @veninvelasques You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

Just
$$\frac{h}{h-30}=\sqrt3,$$ which gives the answer.